# passing data in with require function

Tags: node.js, commonjs

In Node.js (CommonJS module system) we have

```
require('foo');
```

is there a way to pass data to the module, something like:

```
require('foo', {extra:'args'});
```

I'd like to be able to set a value in the module itself as soon as it's loaded, and I don't have control over the structure of 'foo' - it may export a function or the whole module may just run to completion.

**The use-case is actually fairly common:**

I have a module like so:

// foo.js

```
function bar(){


}

if(x){      //if I could pass x as variable to the module, that would be useful
 bar();
}

module.exports = bar;
```

unfortunately, TMK, I have to set a global variable to dictate the value of x, which is always bad.

Comment: If you don't have control over the structure of 'foo', how do you know your arguments will mean anything or do anything?  I mean, the answer is "no".  But I can tell you how to accomplish your real goal if you can explain better why you think you need to do this.

Comment: It's a little difficult to explain why this feature would be useful. It's part of an API. I just added some details.

Comment: If you have been around Node.js long enough, you will have seen this predicament before. Maybe there is a way around it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been around node.js since 2009, hopefully that's long enough. ;)

Generally, what you're asking for isn't possible the way you asked for it.  I've seen four common patterns for configuring modules as you've described.

1) Export a function, pass in params to the function that configure its options.  This is by far the most common approach.

2) Use statics (functions or properties).  This is most common if you treat your module as a Singleton, and the options are things you want to apply to all instances of the module. But most folks shy away from this approach because of global state.

3) Environment variables.  This is another very common way of doing it, and recommended by 12factor.net.  It's most common for app-level variables, less so for inner modules.

4) Config module.  In this case, folks use something like `convict` and others to consolidate configuration from other files (based on environment) and command line args and environment variables.  Modules that need to be configured will just require that and ask for the variables they care about.

Comment: thanks Paul, I never doubted your experience with Node! :) basically this is for an API, and in this case the module needs to execute either completely as a script or wait for the exported function to be called after the script is required. I want the user of the API to be able to decide which type of execution they want. Asking the user to do a lot of setup and use global vars or env vars is always bad, I think, but let me think about your answer some more.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't take it as a slight, but I couldn't resist responding.  I'd suggest looking at other well-documented APIs in the nodeverse.  Generally, the pattern is to pass in options once at the module entry point, and then let them handle anything internally.  But options is the key; there should be smart defaults for pretty much everything.